# How to recover a C++ built-in header file?

Tags: c++, header-files, dev-c++

I did something stupid toda y.I was trying to make my own header file but accidentaly I overwrote the built-in file

```
#include <map>
```

Now I can't use map in my programs. It is showing undefined behavior.

Comment: Lol. What platform ? (What OS ?)

Comment: dev c++ Windows 10 @Boiethios

Comment: A reinstall of the development environment should get back anything you overwrote (uninstall to clean everything out > install to get it all back).

Comment: Just reinstall it.

Comment: @Niall Can't I get the code that is present on map in the net.I mean no other alternative ?

Comment: In the future, consider running under an unprivileged user account so you cannot overwrite SDK files like that.

Comment: Reinstalling it is easier in my opinion. But sure, you can open up the install file you used, search for the "map" header and copy over the contents; but frankly, I suspect you may have done more damage than just overwriting one file when making your own (and then break the standard header). Copying something off the internet may not work as expected, the standard library is often tied (for compatibility) to a version of the compiler.

Comment: @behnc nope, do not do it... Reinstall it and do not run your session with superuser rights as FrédéricHamidi says.

Comment: Thanks everyone :) Maybe I should just just reinstall and not do such stupidity in future :/

Comment: easier to recover than the time I noticed lots of .exe programs on the DOS floppy (comp didn't have a hard disk) and tried them all out... didn't get past `format a:`

Comment: I once worked at a place that did not commit their 'tool chain' to their configuration control (i.e. cvs, git, subversion, etc).  Are you not using one?  And if you do use it, are your tools not part of your commit?

Answer (score 1):

Safest option: Reinstall

If you really don't want to reinstall you could just download the installation files without the setup (as it might be hard to get the files from the packed setup archive) and only replace the headers.

First make sure you know the exact version you have installed. The version of the compiler is important, not the IDE. For https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/ you see 'TDM-GCC 4.9.2 32/64bit'. So looking under 'Files'->'Compilers'->'TDM-GCC' you find this page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/Compilers/TDM-GCC/

Download the archive with your version (in this case the `4.9.2`) in which you'll find an include folder under 'x86_64-w64-mingw32' which should be the one you need. Copy it over your compilers include folder. For more safety check folder structures, versions inside the headers etc. to make sure you really got the right version.

**If in doubt at any point**: Reinstall! Or you might do more harm than good ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I somehow figured out solution without re-installation.

What worked :

1) I typed header file name in new cpp file in dev c++.On hoovering it gave me path of the header file in my pc.

2) Using Quick access in windows 10 I reached desired location where map was actually present.

3) Opened map header file in notepad.It was not modified(don't know why).

4) How I ran random cpp file in dev-cpp which encountered error and open map to show it has error.I overwrite map header with what I have copied from notepad.

5) Ran like wind.Thanks everyone.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't overwrite the compiler version of the file, you just created a new header called "map" in your project directory (or another location that takes priority over the compiler version.